# C++ function not working when called (OOP/matrix class)

Tags: c++, class, oop, matrix, vector

So I'm currently working on my bachelor thesis and I need to code a class hierarchy (using vector and matrix classes) in order to use methods for solving linear systems.

I coded the basic functions for both classes, and even tried them and they were working. But as I started to add more to the code, I noticed that the functions I used for adding elements to a matrix and displaying them basically stopped working although I don't think I modified them in any way (the same functions I used for the vector class still work).

In a way the functions work, because the couts are displayed, but I don't get to input the values at all.

Here's the vector class (and before you say anything, I don't want to use template):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#pragma once

class vector {
protected:
    int n;
    double* vect;

public:
    vector() {
        n = 1;
        vect = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            vect[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    vector(int dim) {
        n = dim;
        vect = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            vect[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    vector(const vector& v) {
        n = v.n;
        vect = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            vect[i] = v.vect[i];
        }
    }

    ~vector() {
        delete[] vect;
    }

    int getsize() {
        return n;
    };

    const vector& operator=(const vector&);
    bool operator== (const vector&) const;
    bool operator!= (const vector&) const;
    void read();
    void display();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const vector&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, const vector&);
};

const vector& vector::operator= (const vector& c) {
    if (this == &c)
        return *this;

    if (this != &c) {
        if (n != c.n) {
            delete[] vect;
            n = c.n;
            vect = new double[n];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            vect[i] = c.vect[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

bool vector::operator== (const vector& c) const {
    if (n != c.n)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (vect[i] != c.vect[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool vector::operator!= (const vector& c) const {
    return !(*this == c);
}

void vector::read() {
    cout << "Insert vector elements:";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> vect[i];
    }
}

void vector::display() {
    cout << "The vector is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << vect[i];
        cout << " ";
    }
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const vector& v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.n; i++) {
        out << " " << v.vect[i];
    }
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, const vector& v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.n; i++) {
        in >> v.vect[i];
    }
    return in;
}
```

and the matrix class is this

```
#include "vector.h"

class matrix {
private:
    int n;
    vector** mat;
public:
    matrix() {
        n = 2;
        mat = new vector * [n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            mat[i] = new vector[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                mat[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    matrix(int dim) {
        n = dim;
        mat = new vector * [n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            mat[i] = new vector[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                mat[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    matrix(const matrix& m) {
        n = m.n;
        mat = new vector * [n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            mat[i] = new vector[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                mat[i][j] = m.mat[i][j];
        }
    }

    ~matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            delete[] mat[i];
        delete[] mat;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const matrix&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, const matrix&);
    void read();
    void display();
    const matrix& operator=(const matrix&);

};

const matrix& matrix::operator=(const matrix& m) {
    if (this == &m)
        return *this;

    if (this != &m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            delete[] mat[i];
        }
        delete[] mat;
        n = m.n;
        mat = new vector*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            mat[i] = new vector[n];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                mat[i][j] = m.mat[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const matrix& m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.n; i++) {
        out << m.mat[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < m.n; j++) {
            out << " " << m.mat[i][j];
        }
        out << endl;
    }
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, const matrix& m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.n; j++)
            in >> m.mat[i][j];
    }
    return in;
}

void matrix::read() {
    cout << "Insert matrix elements:"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cin >> mat[i][j];
    }
}

void matrix::display() {
    cout << "The matrix is:";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << mat[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here's the source as well

```
#include "vector.h"
#include "matrix.h"

int main() {
    vector v1(3);
    v1.read();
    v1.display();
    v1.~vector();
    cout << endl;

    matrix m2(2);
    m2.read();
    m2.display();
    m2.~matrix();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

[I added a picture for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIUUw.png)

Edit 2:
@user4581301 pointed out that I accidentally made a 3D vector, so I turned `vector** mat` into `vector* mat` and created an initialization function in the vector class to help me initialize a vector of vectors.
Now it works! Thanks again!

Comment: `v1.~vector();`, `m2.~matrix();` Don't do that. Destructors are called automatically. That's the whole point. You can just leave both of these out.

Comment: even without those, they're still not working...

Comment: Could you define what "not working" means? Do you get the wrong output? No output? An error?

Comment: You know you could get away with just `class matrix { public: std::vector<std::vector<double>> mat;}` ?

Comment: @GBlodgett I added a picture of the display. I don't get any error in the output bar

Comment: @Jeffrey yeah, but I want to write it the mat[][] way

Comment: @user4581301 okay I fixed the 3D part, but the function still doesn't let me type the values

Comment: `vector** mat;` This declaration means that `mat[i][j]` is a **vector**. You don't want that.

Comment: or mat[i] is a pointer to a single vector, to sue with (*mat[i])[j]. :-) That's one reason OP should definitely consider a modern container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this constructor:

```
    matrix(int dim) {
        n = dim;
        mat = new vector * [n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            mat[i] = new vector[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                mat[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

    }
```

`mat` is `vector**`, so `mat[i][j]` is `vector`. `mat[i][j] = 0;` means "create a vector from `0` and assign that to `mat[i][j]`".

The constructor `vector(int dim)` is used to create a vector from an integer, so zero-element vector is created here.

You will want to use `double** mat;` and `new double` in your `matrix` class instead of `vector** mat;` and `new vector`.

If you really want to use `vector` for the elements of the matrix for some reason, give them positive number of elements. It can be done by, for example, replacing `mat[i][j] = 0;` with `mat[i][j] = vector(1);`.

Also note that you shouldn't call destructors explicitly like `v1.~vector();` and `m2.~matrix();`. They are called automatically when lives of the objects ends and it will lead to double-free problem (thanks @Frank).

Comment: I know that ```double**``` is possible but my prof wants me to use ```vector``` so here we are.

And I know about the destructors. Tbh I added that like half an hour ago just because I didn't know what to do to the code anymore. It wasn't there in the beginning